# Having trouble with a college project (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, string, struct

So im doing a college project, it is a software to manage orders in a pizzeria, i already wrote the code but when i execute the program it only allows me to use the first option of the menu ( besides when i write the ingredient `(option 1)` it crashes).

And it wont do anything when i try to write an order or whatever, im trying to find the problem but i cant see it, any help would be appreciate

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <cmath>
#include <locale>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
const int MAX_INGREDIENTES_PIZZA=10;
const int MAX_PEDIDOS=20;


enum TIngrediente
{
    TOMATE,
    QUESO,
    NATA,
    CEBOLLA,
    POLLO,
    HUEVO,
    SALAMI,
    ANCHOA,
    BACON,
    GAMBA
};

struct TPedido
{
    string nombre_cliente;
    string telefono;
    int numero_pedido;
    int numero_ingredientes;
    array<TIngrediente, MAX_INGREDIENTES_PIZZA> ingredientes;
};

typedef array<TPedido, MAX_PEDIDOS> listado_pedidos;

struct TPizzeria
{
    int numero_pedidos;
    listado_pedidos pedidos;
};


//typedef array<TPedido, MAX_PEDIDOS> listado_pedidos;
const array<string, MAX_INGREDIENTES_PIZZA> INGREDIENTES = {{"tomate", "queso", "nata", "cebolla", "pollo", "huevo", "salami", "anchoa", "bacon", "gamba"}};

TIngrediente StrToIngrediente(string s);
string IngredienteTostr(TIngrediente c);
string tolower(string s);

string tolower(string s)
{
    string r = s;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
        r[i] = tolower(r[i]);
    return r;
}

TIngrediente StrToIngrediente(string s)
{
    s=tolower(s);
    int i;

     while (i < INGREDIENTES.size() and INGREDIENTES[i] != s)
        ++i;
    return (TIngrediente)i;
}

string IngredienteTostr(TIngrediente c)
{
    return INGREDIENTES[c];
}

void inicializar_datos(TPizzeria& p)
{
 p.numero_pedidos=0;
}



void leer_ingrediente(TIngrediente& ing)
{

bool ok=false;
string s;
cout<<"Introduce el Ingrediente a Consultar"<<endl;
while (!ok ){
    int i=0;
    cin>>s;
    s=tolower(s);
    cout<<s<<endl;
    while(i<MAX_INGREDIENTES_PIZZA){
        if (s==INGREDIENTES[i]){
            ok = true;
        }
        cout<<i;
        i++;
    }
    cout<<i<<endl;
    cout<<MAX_INGREDIENTES_PIZZA<<endl;

    if (!ok){
        cout<<"No tenemos disponible ese ingrediente, por favor introduce otro ingrediente que desees"<<endl;
    }
    else {
        ing=StrToIngrediente(s);
    }
}
}


void escribir_ingrediente(TIngrediente ing)
{
    string s;
    s=IngredienteTostr(ing);
    cout<<s<<endl;
}



void leer_pedido(TPedido& ped, bool& ok)
{
    //TPedido p;
    string pedi;
    //bool ok=true;

    getline (cin, ped.nombre_cliente);
    getline (cin, ped.telefono);
    cin >> ped.numero_pedido;
     if (ped.numero_pedido > MAX_PEDIDOS)
        ok=false;
    cin >> ped.numero_ingredientes;
    cin.ignore(100,'\n');
    if(ped.numero_ingredientes > MAX_INGREDIENTES_PIZZA)
        ok=false;
    else{

    for (int i=0; i<ped.numero_ingredientes; i++){
        leer_ingrediente(ped.ingredientes[i]);
    }
    }
    if(!ok){
        cout<<"error"<<endl;
    }

}

void insertar_pedido(TPizzeria& p, TPedido ped, bool& ok)
{
    if(p.numero_pedidos=MAX_PEDIDOS){
        ok=false;
    }
    else{
        p.pedidos[p.numero_pedidos]=ped;
        ok=true;
    }
    //if (!ok){
    //cout<<"error"<<endl;
    //}

}

void escribir_pedido(TPedido ped)
{
    cout<<ped.nombre_cliente<<endl;
    cout<<ped.telefono<<endl;
    cout<<ped.numero_pedido;
    for(int i=0; i<(ped.numero_ingredientes)-1; i++){
        escribir_ingrediente(ped.ingredientes[i]);
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

void escribir_pedidos(TPizzeria p)
{
    for (int i=0;i<p.numero_pedidos; i++){
    escribir_pedido(p.pedidos[i]);
}
}


void eliminar_pedido(TPizzeria& p, int num_pedido, bool& ok)
{
if(num_pedido <= p.numero_pedidos){
    int k=num_pedido-1;
    for (int i=0; i<(p.numero_pedidos)-1-k;i++ ){
    p.pedidos[k+i]=p.pedidos[k+i+1];
    p.pedidos[k+i].numero_pedido-=1;
    }
ok=true;
//int j=p.numero_pedidos;
//p.pedidos[j-1]="";
} else{
    ok=false;
}
}
    //if(ok=true){
        //cout<<"true"<<endl;
    //}
    //else{
        //cout<<"false"<<endl;
    //}
//}

int buscar_pedido(TPizzeria p, string nombre)
{
    int i=0;
    while(p.pedidos[i].nombre_cliente!=nombre and i<p.numero_pedidos){
        i++;
    }
    if(i<p.numero_pedidos){
        return -1;
    }
}

int frec_ingr(TPizzeria p, TIngrediente ing)
{

    int i;
    int suma=0;
    string ingrediente;
    ingrediente = tolower(ing);
    for(int i=0; i<p.numero_pedidos; i++){
        for(int k=0; k<p.pedidos[i].numero_ingredientes; k++){
            if(p.pedidos[i].ingredientes[k]==ing){

                suma++;
            }
        }
    }


    return suma;
}


void frec_ingredientes(TPizzeria p)
{
    int freq;
    TIngrediente ing;
    for(int i=0; i<INGREDIENTES.size(); i++){
        ing = StrToIngrediente(INGREDIENTES[i]);
        escribir_ingrediente(ing);
        cout<<frec_ingr(p,ing);
    }

}

int menu(){

    int m;
    cout<<"Escriba que desea realizar"<<endl;
    cout<<"1 : leer ingredientes"<<endl;
    cout<<"2 : escribir ingredientes"<<endl;
    cout<<"3: leer pedido"<<endl;
    cout<<"4: insertar pedido"<<endl;
    cout<<"5: escribir pedido"<<endl;
    cout<<"6: escribir pedidos"<<endl;
    cout<<"7: eliminar pedido"<<endl;
    cout<<"8: buscar pedido"<<endl;
    cout<<"9: frecuencia de ingrediente"<<endl;
    cout<<"10: frecuencia de todos los ingredientes"<<endl;
    cin>>m;
    return m;
}



int main()
{
    TPizzeria p;
    TPedido ped;
    TIngrediente ing;
    string nombre;
    bool ok;
    inicializar_datos(p);
    int num_pedido;
    int m=menu();
    //int m=menu();
        switch(m){
        case 1 : leer_ingrediente(ing);
        case 2 : escribir_ingrediente(ing);
        case 3 : leer_pedido(ped,ok);
        case 4 : insertar_pedido(p, ped, ok);
        case 5 : escribir_pedido(ped);
        case 6 : escribir_pedidos(p);
        case 7 : eliminar_pedido(p, num_pedido, ok);
        case 8 : buscar_pedido(p, nombre);
        case 9 : frec_ingr(p, ing);
        case 10 : frec_ingredientes(p);
        default: cout<<"no es una opción";
        break;
        }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger, and how to catch crashes "in action" using it.

Comment: so people need to read whole your code and find out what really happen and then report it to you ?

Comment: To be fair, when you are "using first option", you are really using all of them, starting from first. Please read up on `switch` clause for details. Update: Without debugging the code for you, static analyzer present in VS is reporting multiple cases of using uninitialized memory throughout your code. That may be the reason for the crash. Also, there's a single instance of using assignment, instead of comparison, within the `if` clause.

Comment: You should use `break` statement after each case to prevent execution *falling through* to the next case.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have to write the switch sentence [properly](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch), because you are calling all the functions of your switch cases ...

If you want to **do more than 1 option** you have to put the switch statement inside a loop like `for, while, do-while`.
For example, this is the way that i would do it whit a while loop:

```
while(m!=11)
{
    switch(m)
    {
    case 1 : leer_ingrediente(ing);
        break;
    case 2 : escribir_ingrediente(ing);
        break;
    case 3 : leer_pedido(ped,ok);
        break;
    case 4 : insertar_pedido(p, ped, ok);
        break;
    case 5 : escribir_pedido(ped);
        break;
    case 6 : escribir_pedidos(p);
        break;
    case 7 : eliminar_pedido(p, num_pedido, ok);
        break;
    case 8 : buscar_pedido(p, nombre);
        break;
    case 9 : frec_ingr(p, ing);
        break;
    case 10 : frec_ingredientes(p);
        break;
    case 11 : cout << "End of program..." << endl;
    default:
        cout<<"no es una opción";
    break;
    }
    m=menu();
}
```

To do that i added one line to the `menu` function to show one more option to exit of the program:

```
cout<<"11: salir del menu"<<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use break statement after each case to prevent execution falling through to the next case.

```
switch(m){
case 1 : leer_ingrediente(ing);
  break;
case 2 : escribir_ingrediente(ing);
   break;
case 3 : leer_pedido(ped,ok);
  break;
case 4 : insertar_pedido(p, ped, ok);
  break;
case 5 : escribir_pedido(ped);
  break;
case 6 : escribir_pedidos(p);
  break;
case 7 : eliminar_pedido(p, num_pedido, ok);
  break;
case 8 : buscar_pedido(p, nombre);
  break;
case 9 : frec_ingr(p, ing);
  break;
case 10 : frec_ingredientes(p);
  break;
default: cout<<"no es una opción";
break;
}
```

Comment: Deleted the comment.

Comment: Please ignore the previous comment.

Comment: I have rewritten the switch with the breaks and there is no solution. The problem is that whenever i execute a function from the menu it doesnt allow me to execute another one, thing that should be fixed with a while or if but it doesnt, im loocking it over and over again but i cant find a proper solution

Comment: The `switch` statement was the most obvious issue.  There may be more issues.  I suggest you execute your program using a debugger.  You may also want to put `cout` statements to display variable values and to indicate where your program has executed to.